# AngularFire - how to wait for registration to be done?

Tags: typescript, angularfire

I want to upgrade my registration method to log the user immediately after its registration. But the way as below won't work because I'm calling the loginUser() before the firebase register it. How to rebuild my registerUser() to wait until the user exists in server?

```
export class AuthService {

  token: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {}

  registerUser(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
        () => {
          this.loginUser(email, password);
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      )
      .catch(
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript?

Comment: ts actually, but yes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the result of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, use the observable `this.afAuth.authstate`. That observable is updated once the user has logged in, so you would put your post-login functions there. It might look a bit like this:

```
this.afAuth.authstate.subscribe(user=> {
    if (user) {
        //this means the user has logged in
        this.loginUser(email, password);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
```